# View list of all packages in workspace via eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package, workspace

I am starting development on a new project in an existing workspace. I want to try to organize my source in a similar way to the other projects, and use the same general packages when possible. My problem is, I can't remember what packages have been made already. Therefor I was wondering if there was a way to find a list of all the packages in the current workspace. I have found similar questions about viewing a list of projects in a workspace, but haven't found anything yet on listing packages. If someone could help me out that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the package explorer view

view > show view > packages

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this pretty much shows me the same thing as the project explorer view. I want something where I see a list of all packages, across all of my projects. Is there some setting I should change in package explorer to do this or is there another way?

Comment: The package explorer view doesn't really help. However, I thought the packages view would, but it doesn't either, as you can only see the package for a specific project. It still is more useful.

Comment: click on the top right arrow of the package explorer. You can use working sets to customize the view but I don't know if it will do the work. If not, create an eclipse plugin, make it open source, share it to the community and everyone will congrat you ;)

Comment: Ok I guess I was just being dumb. I opened package explorer and not packages view. This works. @ Jeremy It only shows for a particular project if that is what you have selected. I went back to project explorer and selected a high level project, and then went back to packages and it showed everything :)

Comment: Well I guess I am dumber than I thought. Jeremy is right its only showing packages for one project. Still helpful, but not fully solved.